# Showing loading icon on ExtJs 4.1.1 tree panels node when expanded

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, treepanel

I am using ExtJs 4.1.1 tree panel.

```
  xtype: 'treepanel',
                 id: 'tPanel',
                 flex: 0.68,
                 title: 'Tree',
                 displayField: 'DataName',
                 rootVisible: false,
                 useArrows: true,
                 hidden: true,
                 store: 'myStore'
```

This tree is a check tree (shows checkbox). I looked into following example of XML tree:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/example/tree/xml-tree.html

When you expand the node of this tree, it shows loading icon.

[image: Axis is showing loading icon]

**I want to do something similar within my tree panel but I am not able to do so in my tree. Please help**

Comment: what are you doing differently?

Comment: I am using the example given on Sencha site as it is. if I knew what I am doing differently, I would have found the solution. I guess treepanel is not designed this way

Comment: So you are seeing the right behavior on their website but not on yours using the exact same code??

Comment: The problem with Checkbox tree panel on the website is, they have loaded the all the nodes upfront. So there is no need to load them again dynamically. But for other tree's nodes are loaded on request. But when I compare, I don't see any config/property which will do the trick for me.